# Include "space" check in email adress flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, programming-languages

Can someone please tell me how to
add "space" check in email address? I
have tried email.contains("") bt it didnt
worked.

[I don't get a error when i type invalid email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOhOz.png)

```
 import 'dart:async';


class Validators{
  final validEmail = StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(
    handleData: (email, sink){
      if(email.contains('@')){
        sink.add(email);
      }else if(email.contains(" ")){
          sink.addError('Enter a valid email');
      }else{
          sink.addError('Enter a valid email');

      }
    }
  );

  final validPassword  = StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(
    handleData: (password, sink){
      if(password.length > 4){
        sink.add(password);
      }else{
        sink.addError('Enter a valid password');
      }
    }
  );
}
```

[I want "invalid email" error to be displayed as this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOrro.png)

Comment: Can you provide more details about the final result you are trying to achieve and maybe some code? You want to check if the user put only space or you want to detect space at any position in the entered line?

Comment: I want to check if user inserts space in email adress code should return with invalid email adress

Answer (score 3):

Contains works perfectly for me.

```
void main() {
  bool check;
  String email = 'tes t@test.com';

  check = email.contains(' ');

  print(check); // true
}
```

I have tried it on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/)

Perhaps you forgot to put whitespace between quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use hand-rolled regex to validate email addresses.  For one, spaces are in fact permitted in email addresses, as long as they are properly quoted, so the original question is already at fault.  Also, these regex all reject many perfectly valid email addresses, such as my autoresponder at `fred&barney@stonehenge.com`.  (Go ahead... send it email!)

If you're going to validate email, use https://pub.dev/packages/email_validator, which I have confirmed follows the proper rules.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are having is the order in which you validate the email. You should first check for spaces and then for the @ character.

```
handleData: (email, sink){
      if(email.contains(" ")){
          sink.addError('Enter a valid email');
      } else if(email.contains('@')){
        sink.add(email);
      } else{
          sink.addError('Enter a valid email');

      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank- you for your answer. Can u please look at my code and give answer according to it.

Comment: @sls Updated answer

Comment: No, see my answer.  Space is perfectly valid in an email address if quoted properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `Regular Expression` to validate an email address. Although, `regular expressions` are a bit complex to understand, they are very good for validating strings and checking patterns. Here's an example of  a `RegEx` to validate an email address in Flutter/Dart

```
// String p to define pattern
String p = "[a-zA-Z0-9\+\.\_\%\-\+]{1,256}" +
            "\\@" +
            "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}" +
            "(" +
            "\\." +
            "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,25}" +
            ")+";
            //Convert string p to a RegEx
            RegExp regExp = new RegExp(p);
            //If email address matches pattern
            if (regExp.hasMatch(emailAddress)) {
              return 'Email is Valid';
            }else{ //If it doesn't match
              return 'Email is not valid';
            }
```

Comment: No, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to this is to call `trim()` on your email value before passing it. Something like this:

```
new AuthenticationService()
                  .signIn(_emailTextController.value.text.trim(),
                      _passwordTextController.value.text.trim())
```